# Using #import inside code, in if statement

Tags: c++, c, import, ms-office, conditional-statements

I'm building a c/c++ program and I'm using MS Excel for results representation. The problem is that i have to import 2 files:

```
    #import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\MSO.DLL"
    #import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE"
```

It works perfectly on my computer but path to those files is dependent on Windows version(x64/x86) and Office version (11,12,14). 
So my idea is to ask customer for those versions (in main), and then depending on input use different imports. But I dont know how to do that... Something like this doesnt work:

```
    scanf("%d",ver_office);
if (ver_office==1){
    #import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE12\MSO.DLL"
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing a a a c/c++ program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import is performed by preprocessor, so you can't do it in runtime, i.e. you have to know all paths before compilation is started

Comment: any other way? eg. using bat file?

Comment: Common way to do this is to use compiler's option for headers search path. You can set it by using autotools and make, scons, cmake or any other build system as well as simple bat file that will find all paths and feed it to compiler.